# How can I know which image has been downloaded with a custom image pipeline?

Tags: python, scrapy

I created an scrapy item that has two images. Those images need to be post-processed in my Item Pipeline. However, both images have different post-processing needs.

My image pipeline currently looks like this:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images import ImagesPipeline
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

class CustomImagePipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        yield scrapy.Request(item['image_1'][0])
        yield scrapy.Request(item['image_2'][0])

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
        # if image_1 is completed do one thing.
        # if image_2 is completed to another thing.
        return item
```

How can I know which image has been completed in the `item_completed` callback method?

Can I somehow append a field in the `results` dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [the docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/images.html), you can determine which image is which --

```
def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
    for result in [x for ok, x in results if ok]:
        # Invoke relevant post-processing based on result['url']
    return item
```